# regex замена символа

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

Привет всем. пытаюсь с помощью  распарсить строку.

```
#include <regex>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
            string input = "((true);(false);(0))";
            regex regular_exp("\(");
            string replace = "\)";
            res = regex_replace(input, regular_exp, replace);
             cout << "REPLACED - " << res << endl;`
}
```

выдает такое:
  Aborted.
  at abort.c. function __GI_abort () on line 89
  terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
  what():  regex_error

Помогите понять почему так, и как решить проблему!

Answer (score 3):

Мало экранирования, это же строка.
А ещё в строке для замены оно вообще не нужно.

http://ideone.com/cKckAf

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input = "((true);(false);(0))";
    regex regular_exp("\\(");
    string replace = ")";
    string res = regex_replace(input, regular_exp, replace);
    cout << "REPLACED - " << res << endl;
}
```